# renameSync not working when referencing variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

I have created a script to migrate a file from gridfs to the new local C: drive and then rename the file since I am unable to use variables with writeFileSync to dynamically name the file with its extension included.

The issue I am running into is that when I am using any variables in the location path variable it will return an error no such file or directory. When I explicitly write out the string and use no variables, it will find it with no issue and rename the file correctly. Same path, just two different methods for how the path is created. Might be an issue caused by javascript's pass by reference and pass by value? No idea at this point.

I am debugging by console logging all paths as I go to confirm that the final destination string is correct and have already verified that it is exactly the same when using referenced variables as it is when written specifically as a single string.

```
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/tempfile`, data);


unprocessedPath1 = (__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/tempfile`); //DOES NOT WORK
unprocessedPath2 = (__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/${tempFile.filename}`); //DOES NOT WORK
//RETURNS: C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile
//RETURNS: C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile1

// unprocessedPath1 = `C:/Sites/CRM/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/tempfile`; // WORKS
// unprocessedPath2 = `C:/Sites/CRM/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/tempfile1`; // WORKS
//RETURNS: C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile
//RETURNS: C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile1

var correctPath1 = path.normalize(unprocessedPath1);
var correctPath2 = path.normalize(unprocessedPath2);

fs.renameSync(correctPath1, correctPath2, function(err) {
    if ( err ) console.log('RENAME ERROR: ' + err);
});


RENAME ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile' -> 'C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\2019-08-16T10:50.wav'
```

EDIT: Confirmed that file exists at the destination before rename attempt. Added a `console.log(fs.existsSync(correctPath1))` line before rename.

```
true
RENAME ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile' -> 'C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\2019-08-16T10:50.wav'
```

EDIT: Here is the entire request.

```
//DOWNLOAD GRIDFS DATABASE'S OLD FILES AND SAVE TO LOCAL DRIVE
router.get('/export/gridfs', middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
gfs.collection('uploads').find().toArray((err, files) => {

    console.log("OPENING FILES OBJECT: ");    
    console.log(util.inspect(files, false, null, true /* enable colors */));

    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log("FOR EACH FILE");
        tempFile = file;

        console.log("CREATING FILE PRE SAVE");
        File.create(tempFile, function(err, file){
            console.log("FILE PRE CREATED");
            if(err){
                console.log("ERROR OCCURED: " + err);
                console.log("SKIPPING FILE");
            } else {
                console.log("NO ERROR");
                console.log(util.inspect(file, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
                console.log(util.inspect(tempFile, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
                console.log("MAKING NEW FOLDER IN LEAD ID USING FILE ID");
                console.log('public/uploads/' + tempFile.metadata.parent +"/"+ file._id);
                mkdirp('public/uploads/' + tempFile.metadata.parent +"/"+ file._id, function() {});
                console.log("FOLDER CREATED");

                console.log("File Before");
                console.log(file);

                console.log("OPENING file OBJECT: ");
                console.log(util.inspect(file, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
                console.log("OPENING tempfile OBJECT: ");
                console.log(util.inspect(tempFile, false, null, true /* enable colors */))

                file.filename = tempFile.filename;
                file.contentType = tempFile.mimetype;
                file.fileLocation = `/public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${file._id}/${tempFile.filename}`;                    
                file.metadata = { parent: tempFile.metadata.parent };
                file.createdAt = tempFile.uploadDate;
                console.log("filename: " + file.filename);
                console.log("contentType" + file.contentType);
                console.log("fileLocation" + file.fileLocation);
                console.log("metadata: " + file.metadata);

                console.log("File After");
                console.log("FILE: " + file);
                console.log("tempFile: " + tempFile);


                console.log(tempFile.newFileName);
                console.log(tempFile.originalname);
                console.log(tempFile.mimetype);
                console.log(tempFile.contentType);

                console.log("File After");
                console.log(file);

                //save note
                file.save();
                console.log("File Saved");

                const tempId = file._id; 
                console.log("tempId: " + tempId);

                console.log("OPENING tempId OBJECT: ");
                console.log(util.inspect(tempId, false, null, true /* enable colors */));


                console.log("PROCESSING FILE");
                console.log(util.inspect(file, false, null, true /* enable colors */));

                console.log("Starting gridfs stream");

                gfs.files.find({ _id: new ObjectId(file._id) }, (err, file) => {
                    // Check if file
                    console.log("CHECKING FOR FILE ENTRY");
                    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
                        return res.status(404).json({
                            err: 'No file exists'
                        });
                    }

                    console.log("FILE ENTRY FOUND");

                    let data = [];
                    let readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                        filename: tempFile.filename
                    });

                    console.log("Creating read stream");
                    readstream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        console.log("PUSHING CHUNK");
                        console.log(chunk);
                        data.push(chunk);
                        console.log("PUSHED CHUNK");
                    });

                    readstream.on('end', function() {
                        console.log("ENDING STREAM");
                        data = Buffer.concat(data);
                        console.log("WRITING TO LOCAL DRIVE");

                        var fileExt = path.extname(tempFile.filename);
                        console.log(fileExt)


                        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/tempfile`, data);
                        console.log("RETURNING FILE TO CLIENT");

                        console.log("RENAMING FILE AT LOCATION WITH EXTENSION");

                        var unprocessedPath1 = (__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/tempfile`);
                        var unprocessedPath1String = `C:/Sites/CRM/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/tempfile`; //works
                        console.log("Path1: " + unprocessedPath1);
                        console.log("Path1String: " + unprocessedPath1String);

                        var unprocessedPath2 = (__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/${tempFile.filename}`);
                        // unprocessedPath2 = `C:/Sites/CRM/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/tempfile1`; //works
                        console.log("Path2: " + unprocessedPath2);

                        var correctPath1 = path.normalize(unprocessedPath1);
                        console.log("NORMALIZED Path1: "+ correctPath1);
                        var correctPath2 = path.normalize(unprocessedPath2);
                        console.log("NORMALIZED Path2: " + correctPath2);

                        // correctPath1 = String(correctPath1);
                        // correctPath2 = String(correctPath2);

                        console.log(fs.existsSync(correctPath1))
                        console.log(fs.existsSync(unprocessedPath1String))

                        fs.rename(correctPath1, correctPath2, function(err) {
                            if ( err ) console.log('RENAME ERROR: ' + err);
                            console.log("RENAME COMPLETE");
                        });

                    });

                    readstream.on('error', function(err) {
                        console.log('An error occured!', err);
                        throw err;
                    });


                    res.send("EXPORTED");

                });

            }
        });

    });
});
});
```

EDIT: And here is the log.

```
OPENING FILES OBJECT: 
[ { _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
    length: 221228,
    chunkSize: 261120,
    uploadDate: 2019-08-16T17:50:30.212Z,
    filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
    md5: '47fbec41801f73efc53d7e8f73b4e596',
    contentType: 'audio/wav',
    metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' } } ]
FOR EACH FILE
CREATING FILE PRE SAVE
FILE PRE CREATED
NO ERROR
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  contentType: 'audio/wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' },
  createdAt: 2019-08-22T02:50:55.594Z,
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  length: 221228,
  chunkSize: 261120,
  uploadDate: 2019-08-16T17:50:30.212Z,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  md5: '47fbec41801f73efc53d7e8f73b4e596',
  contentType: 'audio/wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' } }
MAKING NEW FOLDER IN LEAD ID USING FILE ID
public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60
FOLDER CREATED
File Before
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  contentType: 'audio/wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' },
  createdAt: 2019-08-22T02:50:55.594Z,
  __v: 0 }
OPENING file OBJECT: 
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  contentType: 'audio/wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' },
  createdAt: 2019-08-22T02:50:55.594Z,
  __v: 0 }
OPENING tempfile OBJECT: 
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  length: 221228,
  chunkSize: 261120,
  uploadDate: 2019-08-16T17:50:30.212Z,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  md5: '47fbec41801f73efc53d7e8f73b4e596',
  contentType: 'audio/wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' } }
filename: 2019-08-16T10:50.wav
contentTypeundefined
fileLocation/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/2019-08-16T10:50.wav
metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' }
File After
FILE: { _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' },
  createdAt: 2019-08-16T17:50:30.212Z,
  __v: 0,
  fileLocation: '/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/2019-08-16T10:50.wav' }
tempFile: [object Object]
undefined
undefined
undefined
audio/wav
File After
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' },
  createdAt: 2019-08-16T17:50:30.212Z,
  __v: 0,
  fileLocation: '/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/2019-08-16T10:50.wav' }
File Saved
tempId: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60
OPENING tempId OBJECT:
5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60
PROCESSING FILE
{ _id: 5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60,
  filename: '2019-08-16T10:50.wav',
  metadata: { parent: '5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c' },
  createdAt: 2019-08-16T17:50:30.212Z,
  __v: 0,
  fileLocation: '/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/2019-08-16T10:50.wav' }
Starting gridfs stream
CHECKING FOR FILE ENTRY
FILE ENTRY FOUND
Creating read stream
(node:3008) DeprecationWarning: GridStore is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Please use GridFSBucket instead
PUSHING CHUNK
<Buffer 52 49 46 46 24 60 03 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 80 bb 00 00 00 ee 02 00 02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 00 60 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >
PUSHED CHUNK
(node:3008) DeprecationWarning: GridStore is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Please use GridFSBucket instead
PUSHING CHUNK
<Buffer 52 49 46 46 24 60 03 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 80 bb 00 00 00 ee 02 00 02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 00 60 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >
PUSHED CHUNK
PUSHING CHUNK
<Buffer 52 49 46 46 24 60 03 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 80 bb 00 00 00 ee 02 00 02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 00 60 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >
PUSHED CHUNK
ENDING STREAM
WRITING TO LOCAL DRIVE
.wav
RETURNING FILE TO CLIENT
RENAMING FILE AT LOCATION WITH EXTENSION
Path1: C:\Sites\CRM\routes/../public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/tempfile
Path1String: C:/Sites/CRM/public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/tempfile
Path2: C:\Sites\CRM\routes/../public/uploads/5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c/5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60/2019-08-16T10:50.wav
NORMALIZED Path1: C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile
NORMALIZED Path2: C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\2019-08-16T10:50.wav
true
true
RENAME ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile' -> 'C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\2019-08-16T10:50.wav'
RENAME COMPLETE
```

Comment: SIDE NOTE: I also already know that it is not wise to include the file extension in public folders due to security risks but this is a close environment and only two users for the application.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear that `C:\Sites\CRM\public\uploads\5d56ebd88f6b3b09f0068f5c\5d56ece48f6b3b09f0068f60\tempfile` does not appear to exist at the exact point in time you are calling `fs.renameSync()`.  That's what the error is telling you.  Also, note that with `fs.renameSync()` there is no third argument for a callback.  That callback argument is only with `fs.rename()`.

Comment: And, `correctPath1 = String(correctPath1);` is completely unnecessary - accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the input jfriend00, I do understand what it is reporting back. That is unfortunately not the issue. The path does work in time when I am using it keyed out as a direct string. When I do it with path.normalize I'm attempting to switch it from a pass by reference variable to a pass by value variable. Didn't know if that was what was causing the error. May of been overkill but also tried the same logic by ensuring it was converted to a unique string not referencing another memory location.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Javascript so there's no need to copy a string to keep it from getting changed.  Every operation that changes a string returns a new string - they never actually change the original.  Further, strings are ALWAYS passed by pointer (not a true reference).

Comment: So, something else  is going on here besides what you show us.  I think we need to see more of the real code in order to help.  By the time you call the `fs.rename()` either the source file no longer exists or there's an access permission or rights issue.  ENOENT usually means the source file wasn't found.  You can try a temporary `console.log(fs.existsSync(correctPath1))` on the line right before the `fs.rename()` as a diagnostic.

Comment: No luck. Updated above with path confirmation. The directory is there. As I said, it works fine when I use only characters in the string. As soon as I use any variables it no longer works so it rules out admin rights and file not being there. Have also confirmed the paths are exactly the same by console logging the paths as shown in the original code above.

Comment: The ***directory*** is there?  `fs.rename()` is for renaming files, not directories.  Nothing more I can do without a reproducible case to debug.

Comment: My apologies, I meant the entire string returned true, both directory path and the file.

Comment: Any chance some other code/process still has the file open, preventing you from renaming it?  Can you rename it manually from an OS shell command line?

Comment: Nope, and have already been able to confirm it works as intended when using the string with no variables. Was successfully able to rename `tempfile` to `tempfile1`. That doesn't work though because there are ~500 files it's going to run through. The filename needs to be a variable and rename works, just not currently with the string containing variables... :/

Comment: Didn't know you were doing this in a giant loop.  That opens up new possible issues - see my answer below now that I can see more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw the new code you added.

This looks to me like shared variables inside a loop using async operations.

Your loop is going to conflict with itself.  The `.forEach()` doesn't wait for your async operations to finish so you'll have multiple iterations of the loop running and trying to use the same variables.  You can fix by either stopping the parallel running of operations in the loop or  by very carefully defining variables with `let` so they are unqiue to each iteration of the loop and using NO shared variables that are ever modified.

The reason there's a problem when you assign to a variable is that variable is in a shared scope and ALL the iterations of the loop are trying to use the same variable, some of them conflicting with one another.

All variables modified inside the `.forEach()` need to be declared internally to the `.forEach()` so they are unique and separate for each iteration of the loop.  None of them should be declared at a higher scope.

The variable `tempFile` is part of the problem.  It will be overwritten by subsequent iterations of the `.forEach()` loop BEFORE some of your asynchronous operations try to use it.  You have so many nested async operations, I haven't studied every single variabled used inside an async callback to see which other ones may have this same issue.

So, the point where you do this:

```
var unprocessedPath1 = (__dirname + `/../public/uploads/${tempFile.metadata.parent}/${tempId}/tempfile`);
```

`tempfile` may well have been overwritten by the next iteration of the loop because this happens in deeply nested asynchronous callbacks that will get called after the `.forEach()` loop has already completed and other values have been potentially written to `tempfile`.

FYI, you show no declaration at all for the `tempFile` variable so perhaps its declared at a higher scope or an accidental module level variable.  Just declaring it as:

```
let tempFile = file;
```

at the top of your `.forEach()` callback will give each invocation of the loop it's own copy of that variable and will fix at least this first issue.

---

As a simplified example of the problem, run this snippet:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4];
const base = "base";
let tempFile;

data.forEach(function(num) {
    tempFile = base + num;
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(tempFile);
    }, 1);
});
```

I use `setTimeout()` here for simplicity's sake as a simple asynchronous callback, but the issue is the same in your code because you're assigning to `tempFile` at each invocation of the loop and then referencing it in asynchronous callbacks.

`console.log(tempFile);` does not show the desired value because the `.forEach()` loop runs to its completion before a single async callback gets called (a product of the node.js event loop and how asynchronous operations use it).

---

Whereas, if you move the declaration of `tempFile` into the loop itself, there's a separate copy of that variable unique to each iteration of the loop and you get the desired output:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4];
const base = "base";

data.forEach(function(num) {
    let tempFile = base + num;
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(tempFile);
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: @IAF - If you haven't seen, I added several more things to my answer, including a simple demo of the type of problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @jfriend00! Will report back after I update.

Comment: @IAF - Please let this be a reminder that witholding the larger context of the actual code can make it a lot harder for you to get an answer and certainly makes it a lot harder for us to help you.  It also eliminates our ability to point you in solution directions that you haven't even though of asking about.  I spend a lot of time here and this happens a lot.  Probably would have seen your issue in 5-10 minutes if we had the larger block of code from the start.

Comment: @IAF - Also, please use `let` instead of `var` as that contains the variable scope to block level which also makes conflicts less likely.

Comment: @AIF - And, `throw err` inside an async callback does nothing useful.

Comment: @AIF - And, I notice you're using `mkdirp()`, presumably to make sure a whole path is properly created, but it's async and you're not waiting for it to complete before continuing.  That probably will cause problems the first time if the whole directory doesn't already exist.

Comment: Understood and will do in the future. Narrowed down the issue to fs.writeFileSync and fs.rename are not allowing me to use the original file name. `2019-08-16T10:50.wav` As soon as I remove the `":"` the script ran correctly.